# How do I make the child-div to have a fixed position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to make the div to be in a fixed position. When I click the parent-div, the child-div toggles down in a relative position. I don't want that. I want the child-div to be in a fixed position so it covers the next div. Like a select.
Working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ubfpzL4c/)

HTML

```
<div class="select-container-funds">
    <div class="select-box-funds">
        <span class="selected-option-funds">
            1
        </span>
        <span class="select-arrow">
            <span class="icon icon-arrow-down-blue"></span>
        </span>
        <div class="funds-info">
            <div class="funds-container">
                <h2>1</h2>
                <p class="funds-data">
                    3 mån %: <span>2.01</span><br />
                    2013 %: <span>2.01</span><br />
                    2012 %: <span>2.01</span><br />
                </p>
                <p>Senast uppdaterat 2014-01-21</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="select-container-funds">
    <div class="select-box-funds">
        <span class="selected-option-funds">
            2
        </span>
        <span class="select-arrow">
            <span class="icon icon-arrow-down-blue"></span>
        </span>
        <div class="funds-info">
            <div class="funds-container">
                <h2>2</h2>
                <p class="funds-data">
                    3 mån %: <span>2.01</span><br />
                    2013 %: <span>2.01</span><br />
                    2012 %: <span>2.01</span><br />
                </p>
                <p>Senast uppdaterat 2014-01-21</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="select-container-funds">
    <div class="select-box-funds">
        <span class="selected-option-funds">
            3
        </span>
        <span class="select-arrow">
            <span class="icon icon-arrow-down-blue"></span>
        </span>
        <div class="funds-info">
            <div class="funds-container">
                <h2>3</h2>
                <p class="funds-data">
                    3 mån %: <span>2.01</span><br />
                    2013 %: <span>2.01</span><br />
                    2012 %: <span>2.01</span><br />
                </p>
                <p>Senast uppdaterat 2014-01-21</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.samo-sans {
  font-family: arial;
}
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
.select-container-funds {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: arial;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.select-container-funds .select-box-funds {
  background: #d3d3d3;
  color: #a9a9a9;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  line-height: 55px;
}
.select-container-funds .select-box-funds.active {
  background: #4682b4;
}
.select-container-funds .select-box-funds > .selected-option-funds {
  padding: 0 1em;
}
.select-container-funds .select-box-funds.funds-info {
  width: 100%;
  background: #4682b4;
}
.select-container-funds .select-box-funds.funds-info.funds-data {
  width: 200px;
}
.select-container-funds .funds-info {
  height: 320px;
  border-top: 2px solid #90ee90;
  display: none;
}
.select-container-funds .funds-info > .funds-container {
  padding: 40px 20px 0 20px;
}
.select-container-funds .select-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 60px;
  height: 55px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #808080;
  text-align: center;
}
```

JavaScript/jQuery

```
$(".select-box-funds").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var isSelected = $(this);
        $(isSelected).children(".funds-info").toggle();
        $(isSelected).toggleClass("active");
});
```

Comment: Sounds to me like you want `position:absolute` rather than `fixed`

Comment: Well, in that case, can you customize my fiddle?

Comment: @Paulie_D The code has been provided and the OP has even done a fiddle. Just because you are looking at more than 5 lines you are all of a sudden a *coding service*?

Comment: Okay, so I set a position to absolute. The problem is that the two other divs are hidden behind the first div. How to split them up?

Comment: yeah, sorry...it's been a bad day and it caught me at the wrong angle in the moment. I'll take a look. Here you go - http://jsfiddle.net/ubfpzL4c/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ubfpzL4c/7/)

```
.funds-info {
    /* I also removed the height previously declared as this is now 'auto' */
    position: absolute;
    z-index:2;
    background: #4682b4;
    width:100%;
    top:100%;
}
```

Comment: Okay! Thanks! My second problem: how do I tell every child-div to have different z-index, so the first one covers the second one, the second one covers the third one and so on? Should I set a class inside every div to have different z-index?

EDIT: Because I'm not actually using only three selects, this select is inside a loop, which iterates 6 times. So how to tell every div to have different z-index?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, the 2nd **does** cover the 3rd..in my demo.

Comment: Okay. I'll take a closer look!

Comment: Let's say you press the first div and then you press the second div. As you can see, the second div is covering the first div when both are "toggled" down. The first div should have z-index: 100, the second one should have a z-index: 99... and so on.

Comment: Ahh...I'm not sure what you have here is really suitable...it sounds like you're after something like an accordion. Jquery has one that **almost** does but it needs some tweaking - http://jsfiddle.net/HotFusionMan/y3vN5/3/

Comment: I see. So it's a pain in the butt in other words to get what I want?

Comment: Sort of, you can write one yourself, I've done it. Here's an early draft of one I had lying around. The animations aren't done and it could use some tidying up but it has the basic functionality. - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/mhwfg

Answer (score 1):

You should modify this css class with folowing properties:

```
.select-container-funds .funds-info {
    position: absolute;
    background: #4682b4;
    z-index: 1; /* should be >=1 */
    width: 100%;
...
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ubfpzL4c/5/)

Comment: I've tried that option as well... Problem occurs when you push the second "select", the first "select" doesn't cover the second one. And the second problem which I haven't figured out yet, how can I make the child-div to have the same width as the parent-div?

Comment: Width: 100% will fix the problem with width

Comment: You want to close first select when the second one is open? Or the first one should be over the second one?

Comment: Hm, nope. What I want is that if you press two divs and both are open, you can compare the info that is inside these two. That's why I want the first div (which is open to have a z-index more than the div under). Hope you understand!

Comment: I added a line in javascript code here http://jsfiddle.net/ubfpzL4c/10/ . Is it what are you looking for? The last clicked div will be above others.

Comment: Yeah, bud!! That's it! Great! :)

Comment: Just in case, I improved the js code a little bit http://jsfiddle.net/ubfpzL4c/11/

Comment: thanks. I notice that code before was bugging for some reason, because I spammed two parent divs, and the div above didn't overlapse the one beneath... hm

Answer (score 0):

Try doing following css changes,

```
.select-container-funds .funds-info {
  height: 375px;
  border-top: 2px solid #90ee90;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100%;
  background: gray;
}
```